# CentOS7 not booting after "yum update" mokListRT fails

Tags: centos7, boot, grub2

I updated CentOS 7 via `yum update`

Didn't know about shim and mokutils so didn't exclude that from yum.

Now I can't boot it, I can recover the files on it using another live distro (e.g. ubuntu), but when I try to run the rescue mode from a CentOS USB key it gives me the same error:

```
Failed to set MokListRT: Invalid Parameter
Something has gone seriously wrong: import_mok_state()
failed: Invalid Parameter
```

Typical solution found is to:

`cp grubx64.efi shimx64.efi`

But the folder in which this file should be ( /boot/efi/EFI/centos ) is completely empty (actually, /boot is empty itself, like not even grub is installed)

Anything else that I can try?

I can at least retrieve the files... but nothing more than that.

Comment: I have this issue as well. Here is the bug report https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=15522

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the [CentOS bug report](https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=15522), this was fixed with the following updates:

> mokutil.x86_64 15-2.el7.centos updates
>   shim-ia32.x86_64 15-2.el7.centos updates
>   shim-unsigned-ia32.x86_64 15-2.el7.centos updates
>   shim-unsigned-x64.x86_64 15-2.el7.centos updates
>   shim-x64.x86_64 15-2.el7.centos updates

Answer (score 0):

If you have one partition for everything try do this:

```
mount -o rw,remount /
```

If you have several partitions in order which they have in fstab remount in rw partitions.

Also looks fine solution described [here](https://angrysysadmins.tech/index.php/2018/12/grassyloki/centos-7-failed-set-moklistrt/)  but check it carefully.

Comment: I already tried to remount them all, setting the RW flag, but it keeps telling me that it's read-only.
I have 3 partitions:
1. the one I need, RO
2. user files ( /home/ ), RW
3. system ( / ), RW
---
Also, already checked that specific link, but can't get that script to work.

Comment: When you try remount partition in RW, (I assume it's boot partition), you got any message(error), you can try to check /var/log/messages?

Comment: No errors. It just says: "The partition is readonly", and yes, it's a boot partition, I guess: it contains EFI folder with the grubx64.efi file in it among other stuff

Comment: @ZioCain Your description doesn't make much sense. Can you explain exactly what you did and exactly what is happening? Don't use vague descriptions; copy and paste everything verbatim.

Comment: Don't hate me, but I just realized that the Read-Only partition wasn't the internal one. So I guess I just have to locate/install grub/shim on the non-booting server and the fix it (?)